# How to remove project within project in XCode?

Tags: xcode

I pasted all files of one folder into another, now it is showing something like this,,

[image]

How can I remove Project within Project and Make one Main Root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is super easy to fix -- What you've accidentally done is drop the 'ShopCadeFinal.xcodeproj' into your Project Navigator.  It is important to recognize that the Project Navigator view of your project is a tree that you manage and not necessarily a 1:1 representation of the filesystem.  If you'd rather, you can think of each of the items in the Project Navigator as a link or shortcut to a file on disk.  This means that your project organization can in fact be different from that of the on-disk filesystem.  Good in that you can safely reorganize files in your project without having to move files around your filesystem or SCM, but that flexibility comes as the risk of accidentally duplicating entries in your project just as you've done with ShopCadeFinal.xcodeproj.

**Ok...so how do I fix it?**

You are probably going to kick yourself because this is so easy:

1. Click on the nested 'ShopCadeFinal.xcodeproj' item
2. Push your delete button.
3. Select 'Remove Reference'.
4. The shortcut to the nested .xcodeproj is gone!

**Won't that delete the source code of my actual project file?**

Nope!  Not at all as long as you've selected the 'Remove Reference' option instead of 'Move to Trash'.  The nuances about the Project Navigator being a collection of links or shortcuts from the mini-lecture at the top of this answer is the key -- You are simply removing the duplicate .xcodeproj reference in your Project Navigator, not actually deleting anything from disk.

**Ok, I have other files I duplicated.  How do I deal with those?**

In just the same way -- select the duplicate reference, push delete and select 'Remove Reference'.

**I ran into some other quirky issue...**

Tack a note on this answer with what you are seeing and lets see if we can figure it out!

Comment: It should be noted that there are reasons for wanting to have multiple project files.  This makes it easy to have both iOS and OSx projects, eg.  Yes, you can IN THEORY do this with a single project file with the latest Xcode, but you couldn't really do it with earlier versions, and I'm not sure the latest works all that well.  Of course, if you do this you have to manually maintain the second (third, fourth...) project when you add/remove files in the first, but that's not all that difficult.

Comment: Completely agree with having multiple project files -- Thanks!  When using Workspaces, you do have to think about your project somewhat differently.  Nice is some regards, but can definitely turn sour if not managed properly.